# unable to get packages from source

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang, cli, cargo

```
warning: please specify `--format-version` flag explicitly to avoid compatibility problems
error: failed to download `lock_api v0.4.9`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/home/mateo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lock_api-0.4.9/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  could not parse input as TOML

Caused by:
  TOML parse error at line 1, column 1
    |
  1 |
    | ^
  Unexpected ``
  Expected key or end of input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lately you get this error when compiling your code do this: go to `.cargo/registry`, then delete the src folder with `rm -r src/`